# Change of place of birth name on UK BRP card

Tags: uk-visa

The government has changed my place of birth city name from "Gulbarga" to "Kalaburagi". I recently got my passport renewed and got the place of birth name changed to "Kalaburagi". However, my BRP still holds the old name ("Gulbarga"). Do I need to go for a change of this in my BRP card? Can you please suggest?

Comment: To be clear, this is just a change in spelling/Anglicisation? These two places are the same but spelt differently?

Comment: Hi MJeffryes, thanks for your reply. yes, the place is the same, only the name is changed. Earlier it was "Gulbarga" and now renamed to "Kalaburagi". My renewed passport has the new name ("Kalaburagi") now. However, my BRP still has the old name ("Gulbarga"). So, do I need to update my BRP to include this new name?